# Product of geodesic distances

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm working on trying to show this, but can't seem to get started. No guarantees that it is true, but other conditions on the adjacency matrix that make it true or a counter example are helpful. Thanks for any help.

Define $d(i,j)$ to be the geodesic distance between two graph nodes $i$ and $j$. Say an $N$ node undirected graph is symmetric (this is my own definition) if:

$ \sum_{j=1}^N d(i,j) = c, \ \ \forall i$

Show that for symmetric, connected, non-trivial (i.e. not complete) graphs:

$ d(i,a) > d(i,b) \implies \sum_{j=1}^N d(i,j) d(a,j) \leq \sum_{j=1}^N d(i,j) d(b,j) $

To aid (possible) intuition here are a few graphs that satisfy the above condition. A circle graph:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
$

Another example is a slightly incomplete star graph:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if a graph is vertex-transitive, then it is `symmetric' by symmetry and we can wlog assume $i = 1$. The skeleton of the *truncated icosidodecahedron* is a counter-example to your conjecture, since the following plot (of $d(1, a)$ on the horizontal axis against $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N d(1,j) d(a,j)$ on the vertical axis) is not monotonically decreasing:

[image: Counter-example to your conjecture]

Comment: Thanks for the counter example, this is useful. Do you have any intuition of what sort of structure I could impose on graphs for this property to hold?

Comment: Well, the counter-example shows that vertex-transitivity is not enough. My friend and colleague Gabriel Gendler proved that Kneser graphs and cycle graphs have your property, so maybe arc-transitivity suffices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc-transitive_graph

Comment: Actually, arc-transitivity isn't enough, either; the Dyck graph lacks your property (and has just 32 vertices).

Comment: The Dyck graph is particularly illustrative as it is one that I would have intuitively thought would have my property. Would you or Gabriel mind sharing a sketch of the proof for Kneser and cycle graphs? My cycle graph proof is really messy and doesn't point at all towards constraints I may be able to impose.

Comment: I've been playing around a bit more with specific structures and using your Mathematica code to check the example graphs. Distance-transitive graphs may be a promising class http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-transitive_graph .